# CustomValidator on saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a page (aspx), in it there is a text box (Brand auto) and the button on saving.
It is necessary that **if** in the Brand of the auto (in textbox) the user specified the following designations and pressed the button to save, shall work the validator and not save.

```
I created in a DB the table and procedure with these designations:
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | %BM% | 
| 2  | %T-3% |

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[vehicle_select] 
    @mark nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if exists
    (Select  Name 
        From ogpo_specialize_vehicle
        where @mark Like Name)
        Select 1 as Vle
    else 
        select 0 as Vle
END
```

I created QueriesAdapter.
**Code:**

```
protected void Mark_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
 (new DataSetVehiclesTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter()).ogpo_specialize_vehicle_select(Mark);             
 if(dt.VleColumn == 1 )
 {
   e.IsValid = false;
 }
  else
  {
  e.IsValid = true;
  }}
```

Help what to write in a condition? Conditions the wrong

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl, I incorrectly write a condition

Answer (score 0):

in stored procedure add one more parameter: *@Vle int;*

Instead of *SELECT 1 as Vle* use *Set @VLE = 1*
The same thing for 0.
In code behind:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedure_name", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mark", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = your_value;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string result = cmd.Parameters["Vle"].Value.ToString();
con.Close();
```

Comment: where is the condition?

Comment: change your query in procedure to the following:

Comment: Select  Name 
        From ogpo_specialize_vehicle
        where lower(@mark) Like lower('%Name%')

Comment: It is your query with condition

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
protected void Mark_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        DataSetVehicles1TableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter ds = new DataSetVehicles1TableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
        string mark = args.Value;
        string result = ds.ogpo_specialize_vehicle_select(mark.ToUpper()).ToString();
        if (result == "0")
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```